# Python pyodbc error "Could not delete from specified tables"

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

I am intermittently getting the below error while deleting records from MS Access DB table from a python code using the `pyodbc` library

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [MICROSOFT][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not delete from specified tables. (-3049) (SQLExecDirecW)

There are 2 delete statements in the code and the above error is intermittenly shown

```sql
DELETE * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CASE_ID IN ('ABC')
DELETE * FROM TEMP_TABLE
```

The weird thing is that if I run the code again it works fine without any code changes.  This python code is run daily Mon-Fri, so the code works fine for 2-3 and then it fails or sometime it works for couple of weeks then it fails.

The above delete statements are executed on the cursor object like

```py
cur.execute("DELETE * FROM TEMP_TABLE")
```

The Access database is kept on a shared drive and the connection is established using the `pyodbc` library with the full network path.  So there is no issue in establishing the connection with the Access DB.  In the code there is `insert` as well as `update` statements and they are all working fine.

The tables where the data is deleted has a primary key defined on the case_id column.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: When running this maintenance script, are there any other systems accessing this Access db file?

Comment: There are 2 other users who extract reports from the DB, they might be using it, hard to tell.

Comment: The `HY000` error can mean that you're using a cursor object to run a new query, when that cursor object was used to run a prior query that still has results remaining.  Was the `cur` cursor object used to run another query prior to the one that had the error?

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon I am using the same cursor object for multiple db operations.

Comment: Did you fetch all the results from the previous query, before using the same cursor to run a new query?

Comment: In one function, I am deleting all records from temp_table, inserting records into the temp_table(only one column), run an update statement on another table using the data in the temp_table, deleting all records from the temp_table.  And finally commiting the changes.

Comment: everytime I am closing the cursor object properly before closing the connection object

Comment: That's not what I asked.  Did you **fetch all of the results from the previous query**  before using the same cursor object to run a new query?

Comment: @JohnGordon using the cursor object I am only doing a delete, insert and update operation.  What results should I be fetching from a delete, insert and update operation?  And how should I fetch the results from a delete, insert and update operation on a cursor - sqlrowcount?

Comment: @JohnGordon no I am not fetching any results from the previous query

Comment: Usually there is a `.fetchall()` method on the cursor to fetch all of the remaining results.

Comment: ok I will try it and revert back to you

Comment: @JohnGordon the `.fetchall()' method of the cursor only works on SELECT query, when I used it for delete/insert or update statement, it raises an Exception "pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results. Previous SQL was not a query"

Comment: Hmm.  Well, maybe that wasn't the problem after all.

Comment: For a [mre], please post a fuller code block and not a single line snippet. As above comments indicate we need more context. Don't tell us the code. Please show us with an [edit] to post and not as long comments.